# How is the double-at @@ syntax used in LESS?

Tags: less

```
@var = 'foo'
@foo = 'bar'
```

`@@var` gives you `'bar'`?

What's the use of this technique?

Answer (score 4):

It allows you to change which variable is called dynamically. I use this feature in PHP with double-dollar-sign $$.

```
$var = 'bar';
$bar = 'hello';
echo $$var; // Output is hello
```

You can think about it as $($var), where it evaluates the inner expression then evaluates the outer with the result of the inner. I once used this in a sanitation of user input.

```
// In a controller
for(array('email', 'firstname', 'lastname') as $input){
    $$input = $_POST[$input]; //Will create a variable with that name
    sanitation_function( $$input ); //This will sanitate the input
}
```